# Add Secondary Windows Phone 8 Tile

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an app which adds a secondary tile to the user's homescreen. I would like to make that tile wide by default. However, despite enabling it is a wide tile it is never wide when initially added, which forces the user to resize it manually.

I would really like to avoid making the user resize the tile manually, and there is a sample application which definitely adds a wide tile with the press of a button. Unfortunately the code they use to do so is precompiled and obscured.

I know it MUST be possible to add a secondary wide tile which is already wide at the time it is added. Would greatly appreciate any and all help in the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't force the user to use a wide tile.