# WP8: Creating a wide secondary tile

Tags: windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Secondary Windows Phone 8 Tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925129/add-secondary-windows-phone-8-tile)

I am wondering if there is a way to pin a secondary tile in the Wide-mode, so the user doesn't have to resize it after it is pinned?